# ActiveStorage multiple upload with intermediate model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, file-upload, rails-activestorage

### The goal

I want to upload multiple files. So one **Intervention** can have multiple **Uploads** and each **Upload** has one attached file to it. This way, each **Upload** can have one file attached with different status, name, visibility, etc. instead of having one **Upload** with `has_many_attached`

---

### What I have done

I have one Intervention model that can have many uploads :

```
class Intervention < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :uploads, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :uploads, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Each uploads has one attached file using ActiveStorage :

```
class Upload < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :intervention
  has_one_attached :file
end
```

In my interventions_controller I do :

```
def new
  @intervention = Intervention.new
  @intervention.uploads.build
end

def create
  @intervention = Intervention.new(intervention_params)
  # + default scaffolded controller [...]
end

def intervention_params
  params.require(:intervention).permit(:user_id, :comment, uploads_attributes: [:status, :file])
end
```

In my form I have :

```
<%= form.fields_for :uploads, Upload.new do |uploads_attributes|%>
    <%= uploads_attributes.label :file, "File:" %>
    <%= uploads_attributes.file_field :file %>

    <%= uploads_attributes.hidden_field :status, value: "raw" %>
<% end %>
```

---

### Problem

This solution works when I want to upload only one file. But if I want to upload two files I can't figure out. I can add `multiple: true` to the `file_field` but how to created multiple Upload with one file each ?

Should I save the uploaded files into a temp variable first, extract them from the `intervention_params`, then create the Intervention without any Upload, then for each uploaded files saved, build a new Upload for the newly created Intervention ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done what I have proposed. I don't know if there is a more elegant way to do it but anyway, this is working.

In my form I just added a simple `files` field that can take multiple files

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :files %>
  <%= form.file_field :files, multiple: true %>
</div>
```

I have added this to the permitted parameters :
`params.require(:intervention).permit(:user_id, :comment, files:[]])`

Then I create my **Intervention** by ignoring this `files` params and I use it later to create a new **Upload** record for each files submitted.

```
# First create the intervention without the files attached
@intervention = Intervention.new(intervention_params.except(:files))

if @intervention.save
  # Then for each files attached, create a separate Upload
  intervention_params[:files].each do |f|
    upload = @intervention.uploads.new()
    upload.file.attach(f)
    upload.save
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for posting; I also found this to be the best solution, even though it doesn't seem to conform with the conventional rails way.